PC Randomly Freezing once in 2-3 days
My PC randomly freezing once in few days, hard shutdown only saves the day. Afterwards it works perfectly fine.
Fresh windows 11 installation, once the issue occured i thought that might be the BIOS, so I updated it to f10 but upon turning RAM's XMP it froze non stop and then rolled back to default bios version. So i installed BIOS again without turning XMP this time, and seemed fine until today when i woke up the PC from sleep it froze completely after 3-4 minutes.
Pc Specs:
Windows 11 pro
Gigabyte z590 aorus master bios version f10
Intel core i9 11900k
GeForce rtx 3070ti
Samsung ssd 980 pro 1tb + hdd 1tb
RAM Corsair Vengeance DDR4 16gb+16gb
Asus ROG-STRIX Modular 750W GOLD PSU
View: https://imgur.com/a/gfvBihA
event viewer
A bit frustrated on solving this issue. If it's a hardware issue any idea which part is corrupted?

The error you are getting on the event viewer is an unexpected power loss, I suggest you check power supply and your hardware with an hardware scan

Have you run a long memory test?

Hardware checked all good.

Read that it could be connected to dual monitor setup HDMI/ DP connections and G sync option. Disabled g sync on both monitors - today pc didnt freeze. Will update. Both monitors are Samsung
